# How to parse json in php when json_decode, stripslashes and other solutions are not working?

Tags: php, json, rest, parsing, jsonparser

I know this type of question has been asked multiple times on this forum, but I have looked at countless variations of the question and have tried many different solutions and none of it is working, so I thought I would paste my actual code in case I am totally missing something. So I am accessing an API for a CRM and receiving json output. The output is seen as below:

```
{"access_token":"415db7610058604900566bdd","expires":1639406913,"expires_in":3600,"scope":"granted_permission","domain":"bitrix24.com","server_endpoint":"https:\/\/oauth.bitrix.info\/rest\/","status":"L","client_endpoint":"https:\/\/bitrix24.com\/rest\/","member_id":"**************","user_id":8,"refresh_token":"31dcde610058604900566bdd00000008f0f1037319823fdbcad5b438d3098146949075"}
```

This is the output I get after using cURL to post a URL that then allows a refresh_token to be generated, which can be seen in the json output. I have to parse the json in order to get the new refresh token so that I can re-enter it when the token has expired.

After research I learned that you can parse json via PHP by using the json_decode function, I have tried this in many different ways, trying the function with trim, true, stripslashes and many more variations.

When I run the below code I can echo the $result variable and see the json, but when I try and echo just the refresh_token which I have parsed from the json output, all I get is a blank screen, no matter which method I try and use or even if I var_dump. If someone could explain what I have done wrong, whether I am supposed to be importing some sort of external library or whether I have missed a step somewhere, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);

$client_id = "**********";
$secret_id = "****************";
$refresh_token = "94dade610058604900566bdd00000008f0f103f252c645ad3779a511ca2346b2fe9f27";
$refresh_token2 = "";


if($refresh_token2 == "") {
    $url = "https://bitrix24.com/oauth/token/?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=" . $client_id . "&client_secret=" . $secret_id . "&refresh_token=" . $refresh_token . "&scope=granted_permission&redirect_uri=app_URL";

    // Initialize a CURL session.
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Return Page contents.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //grab URL and pass it to the variable.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
    

    $json = file_get_contents($result);
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    var_dump($obj);


}
```

---

---

Here I tried @dietcheese solution. I also added a screenshot of the output showing how it doesn't output the json value. This is what I meant by I have tried solutions posted on the forum before (@dietcheese solution being of one them) and they do not work.

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);

$client_id = "**************";
$secret_id = "**************";
$refresh_token = "250be0610058604900566bdd";
$refresh_token2 = "";


if($refresh_token2 == "") {
    $url = "https://bitrix24.com/oauth/token/?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=" . $client_id . "&client_secret=" . $secret_id . "&refresh_token=" . $refresh_token . "&scope=granted_permission&redirect_uri=app_URL";

    // Initialize a CURL session.
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Return Page contents.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //grab URL and pass it to the variable.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "This is the result variable being echoed: \n\n" . $result;
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
    echo "\n\n\nHere the json should print: \n\n";
    print_r($json);
    echo "\n\nHere the refresh token should echo: \n\n";
    echo $json['refresh_token'];


}
```

Below is the output:
[image]

This is why I asked the question because I am genuinely confused as to how nothing is working.

Comment: *"...but when I try and echo just the refresh_token which I have parsed from the json output..."* I don't see anything in that code that does anything at all with the parsed result other than dump it out via `var_dump`. Where/how do you think you're getting the refresh_token from it in that code?

Comment: Why do you use `file_get_contents()` with the JSON response?

Comment: `$json = file_get_contents($result);` But `$result` is not a file name its a string containing the results of the cURL call

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, there's nothing wrong with that JSON at all. `json_decode` will successfully decode it, and using `$obj->refresh_token` on the result will give you the `refresh_token`. So the problem is in getting the JSON, probably because of one of the issues listed above.

Comment: So just `echo $result;` and you will be sending a JSONString back to the Javascript, which javascript knows how to deal with

Comment: You don't say what `json_decode()` returns and you don't ask or check for JSON decoding errors. A blank screen typically means your development box is not configured to display errors. Given that you don't know what PHP complaints about, the error could be anywhere in your codebase.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. @T.J.Crowder the code I posted was a test to dump the entire JSON just to see if I even get anything, this was after trying to display one value did not work. The reason why I used `file_get_contents` was the fact that I was using other answers found on the forum, but I am glad that it is not necessary. I appreciate all the feedback and will learn from this.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, I have updated my question to show where I tried @dietcheese solution with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using

```
$json = file_get_contents($result);
```

After your curl_close($ch) statement, try adding:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($json);
```

If that works, you should be able to do something like:

```
echo $json['refresh_token'];
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue. Thank you to @ÁlvaroGonzález for his reminder that I should have debugging active in my codebox. (I know a rookie move, but I am still a rookie).

After enabling debugging, I found that PHP did not even recognise json_decode. After then installing the JSON module for PHP, everything works.